# Passing form variable into php curl request

Tags: php, curl

I've searched the site extensively and I just can't get the syntax correct in my attempt to replace a parameter in a Curl request with data inserted from a form.

This code works:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_PORT => "8000",
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://nd-337-495-552.rg-709-313.p2pify.com:8000",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"method\":\"liststreamitems\",\"params\":[\"Device\"],\"chain_name\":\"nw-504-042-6\"}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: Basic abcdefghijklmnop1234567=",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Postman-Token: dd629e44-26fb-4ed1-ac4e-c47faf38c356",
    "cache-control: no-cache"
  ), // auth header content deliberately changed
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

This code, where I try to replace "nw-504-042-6\" with the variable $ChainName in CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS does not work.

```
<?php

$ChainName = $_POST['ChainName'];
$StreamName = $_POST['StreamName'];

echo $ChainName;

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_PORT => "8000",
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://nd-337-495-552.rg-709-313.p2pify.com:8000",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"method\":\"liststreamitems\",
\"params\":[\"Device\"],
\"chain_name\":"'"$ChainName"'"}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: Basic abcdefghijklmnop1234567=",
    "Postman-Token: 0bcbbec4-cc25-4059-b2c4-220c4722b9d5",
    "cache-control: no-cache"
  ), // auth header content deliberately changed
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Would appreciate the assistance

Comment: hello `romantic_nightingale`, please avoid showing your credentials in public posts. Only one thing left to do, request new userid:pass from the API provider. Editing the post is not good enough, the edit history will show thine token.

Comment: read all about **[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)**, please dont bake your own encoding.

Comment: I'd build the contents of your `CURLOPTS_POSTFIELDS` as an associative array first, then simply `json_encode` it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to `json_encode` your params

```
$params = [
  "method"=>"liststreamitems",
  "params"=>["Device"],
  "chain_name"=>$ChainName
];
```

Then pass it to the option `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` like this

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($params);
```